# cakephp3の動作確認について

Tags: vagrant, xampp

cakephp3の開発をvagrant環境にて作成し、アプリをwindowsにてxamppでも確認する為、htdocsにフォルダごと保管（例：C:\xampp\htdocs\testapp）し、実行しました。
結果、cssが全く読み込めていない状態となるのですが、xampp（apache？）でどのような設定をすれば、vagrant環境で作成したアプリを正常に読み込めるようになるでしょうか？

Comment: 読み込めないとのことですが、直接ブラウザにCSSのURLをアクセスするとどのようなメッセージが出ますか？（404や403等）またxamppのapacheのアクセスログもしくはエラーログは見ることができますでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
直接アクセスすると「Object not found!・・・Error 404・・・」という内容が表示されます。
また、エラーログには出力されておらず、アクセスログには[

Comment: 「/testapp/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1305・・・」のように出力されています。